# New GUI builder from CodeNameOne introduces exception?

Tags: java, exception, codenameone, gui-builder

I am testing new GUI builder and just by clicking new stuff to the GUI, I can't get thru a runtime exception:

> Compiling 1 source file to
>   /home/peter/Projekty/NetBeans/CN1_TestNewBuilder/TestNewBuilder/build/tmp
>   Compiling 1 source file to
>   /home/peter/Projekty/NetBeans/CN1_TestNewBuilder/TestNewBuilder/build/classes
>   compile: run: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1004)  at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:56)    at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Java
>   Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

I did not add a single line of my own code yet. At least I am not aware of anything :)
Will anyone help me ?

Comment: Put the GUI builder away.  Build around 250 Swing GUI's by hand, making sure to use all of the Swing layout managers 20 - 30 times each.  Once you've accomplished your 250 Swing GUI's, then you're ready to test an experimental GUI builder.

Comment: Anyone, any other suggestion ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Le Blanc And yes, I appreciate and highly esteem the CN1 project (that is why I am fighting to graps it), if that is behind your sarcasm :)

Comment: FYI @GilbertLeBlanc question is about Codename One not Swing....

Comment: Gilbert perhaps meant, that instead of using CN1 and its facilities, I could manually swing for iOS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you renamed or changed the package of your main application after project creation: `com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication`.

This is unrelated to the GUI builder. We suggest not doing that as package names are **important** and identify your apps to the stores. If you still want to change them you need to change them everywhere...

Comment: Indeed, that I did - namely I renamed the class name. 
But I used in NetBeans the menu: Right Click @ class name -> Refactor -> Rename, which I assumed to do the job of renaming everything for me.
I remember that in tutorial video you suggest not to rename it, once it was established.
Thank you for this hint.

Comment: The IDE handles everything it can "see". So it can't see some of our more complex configuration options.